# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This question is closely related to this [other one in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131818).)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number.

From this [paper in NNTDM](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/), we have the equation
$$i(q) := \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right).$$

In particular, we know that the *index* $i(q)$ is an integer greater than $5$ by a result of Dris and Luca.

We now attempt to compute an expression for $\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right)$ in terms of $i(q)$.

First, since we have 
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma({q^k}{n^2}) = \sigma(N) = 2N = 2{q^k}{n^2}$$
we obtain
$$\sigma(q^k) = \frac{2 q^k n^2}{\sigma(n^2)} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(n^2)/q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{i(q)}$$
and
$$\sigma(n^2) = \frac{2 q^k n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = {q^k}\cdot\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg) = {q^k}{i(q)},$$
so that we get
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{i(q)}, {q^k}{i(q)}\bigg).$$

Now, since $\gcd(q, n) = \gcd(q^k, 2n^2) =  1$ and $i(q)$ is odd, we get
$$\gcd\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{i(q)}, {q^k}{i(q)}\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\frac{n^2}{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg).$$

Hence, we conclude that $G:=\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd\bigg({n^2}/{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg)$.

*(Edited Sept 12 2017)* Here are my questions:

Original Question

> I seem to recall that somebody (was it Pomerance [?] et. al) proved that
>   $$G \neq 1.$$  Does anybody here happen to know a reference?  Additionally, does
>   $G \neq 1$ imply that $G = i(q)$?

Additional Question *(Added Sept 12 2017)*

> Some authors have already considered the possibility that $i(q)$ may be a square.  This would imply that $G$ is also a square.  Would $G$ a square mean that $G = i(q)$ holds?

*(End Edit)*

Thank you.

Comment: $G = i(q)$ if $i(q) \mid n$.  Usually, this is the case when $i(q)$ is prime (since $i(q) \mid n^2$ must hold).  Alas, the statement $i(q)$ is prime has been disproved in [Chen and Chen (2012)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972712000032).

Comment: If the downvoter could kindly explain his/her vote, I would consider it as constructive feedback.  As it is, I am totally clueless.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131818

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that
$$G \text{ is a square } \iff i(q) \text{ is a square.}$$

The proof is essentially contained in this [answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3132355/28816).

Thus, we have the implication
$$G \text{ is a square } \implies k=1$$
by a result of Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou ([Improving the Chen and Chen Result for Odd Perfect Numbers](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf)).

Comment: In fact, we have the implication
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = 1 \implies k = 1,$$
per [this answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4249583/28816).

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a conditional proof that 
>   $$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$

As derived in the OP, we have
$$G = \gcd\bigg(\frac{n^2}{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg).$$

This is equivalent to
$$G = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\gcd\bigg(n^2, (i(q))^2\bigg) = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\bigg(\gcd(n, i(q))\bigg)^2.$$

But we also have
$$\gcd(n, i(q)) = \gcd\bigg(n, \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(n^2), \gcd(n, n^2)\bigg) = \gcd(\sigma(n^2), n).$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$G = \frac{\bigg(\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))}.$$

In particular, we get
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k), \sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
if and only if
$$\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = i(q).$$