# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part III

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Let $m = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is [known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280897) that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}$$
and therefore that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \geq 3$$
if and only if $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$.

Lastly, it is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4249583/28816) that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=1$$
implies $k=1$.

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Under what conditions is it true that
> $$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))?$$

I know that the **GCD** equation is true, for example, when $\sigma(n^2) = q^k n$ (and therefore, $\sigma(q^k) = 2n$).  Are there other conditions under which the **GCD** equation is true?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p^s Q^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv s \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,Q)=1$.

I did some more digging on when the equations

$$\gcd(Q^2, \sigma(Q^2)) = \gcd(\sigma(Q^2), \sigma(p^s))$$
$$\gcd(Q, \sigma(Q^2)) = \gcd(Q^2, \sigma(Q^2))$$
$$\gcd(\sigma(Q^2), \sigma(p^s)) = \gcd(Q, \sigma(Q^2))$$

simultaneously hold.  Note that we have the identity

$$\gcd(\sigma(Q^2), \sigma(p^s)) \gcd(Q^2, \sigma(Q^2)) = \left(\gcd(Q, \sigma(Q^2))\right)^2.$$

**Hence, when exactly one of the three equations above holds, then the other two equations follow.**

---

In particular, note that
$$\gcd(Q^2, \sigma(Q^2)) = \gcd(\sigma(Q^2), \sigma(p^s))$$

is equivalent to
$$\frac{Q^2}{\sigma(p^s)/2} = \frac{\left(\gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q)\right)^2}{\sigma(p^s)/2}$$

which, in turn, is equivalent to

$$Q = \gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q).$$

This last GCD equation holds if and only if $Q \mid \sigma(p^s)/2$.

---

Furthermore, in particular, note that
$$\gcd(Q, \sigma(Q^2)) = \gcd(Q^2, \sigma(Q^2))$$

is equivalent to

$$\left(\frac{Q}{\sigma(p^s)/2)}\right)\cdot\gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q) = \frac{Q^2}{\sigma(p^s)/2}$$

which, in turn, is equivalent to

$$\gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q) = Q.$$

This last GCD equation holds if and only if $Q \mid \sigma(p^s)/2$.

---

Lastly, in particular, note that
$$\gcd(\sigma(Q^2), \sigma(p^s)) = \gcd(Q, \sigma(Q^2))$$

is equivalent to
$$\frac{\left(\gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q)\right)^2}{\sigma(p^s)/2} = \left(\frac{Q}{\sigma(p^s)/2}\right)\cdot\gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q)$$

which, in turn, is equivalent to

$$\gcd(\sigma(p^s)/2, Q) = Q.$$

This last GCD equation holds if and only if $Q \mid \sigma(p^s)/2$.

---

Thus, if we set
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(Q^2), \sigma(p^s))$$
$$H = \gcd(Q^2, \sigma(Q^2))$$
$$I = \gcd(Q, \sigma(Q^2))$$

then we get the biconditional

> $$G = H = I \iff Q \mid \sigma(p^s)/2.$$

Of course, as a sanity check, when $\sigma(p^s) = 2Q$, then we obtain the conjunction

$$Q \mid \sigma(p^s)/2$$

and

$$\sigma(p^s)/2 \mid Q,$$

which by [Conjunction Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) yields

$$Q \mid \sigma(p^s)/2$$

and hence, that

$$G = H = I.$$

Comment: A suggestion: the huge parentheses might be easier to read with `\big` rather than `\Bigg`; for example, $\dfrac{\gcd\bigl(n\sigma(n^2), i(q)\bigr)}{i(q)}$ `\dfrac{\gcd\bigl(n\sigma(n^2), i(q)\bigr)}{i(q)}` rather than $\dfrac{\gcd\Biggl(n\sigma(n^2), i(q)\Biggr)}{i(q)}$ `\dfrac{\gcd\Biggl(n\sigma(n^2), i(q)\Biggr)}{i(q)}`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @LSpice!  Incorporating these changes in the post now.